# Having same page footer when open RSS pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova-3

When I click on RSS items in my mobile app, I would like to see same page  footer as I have in my first page. I've created my app using Cordova 4.3.0, jQuery mobile and read RSS feeds using jQuery in my onDeviceReady() function in index.js file as follow:

```
  onDeviceReady: function () {
          $(function () {
                    $.get('http:myRssUrl.cshtml',function(data) {
                    var $XML = $(data);
                    var html = '';
                         $XML.find("item").each(function() {
                                   var $this = $(this),
                                   item = {

                                           title:       $this.find("title").text(),
                                           link:        $this.find("link").text(),
                                           description: $this.find("description").text(),
                                           pubDate:     $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                                           author:      $this.find("author").text(),
                                           enclosure:   $this.find("enclosure").attr('url'),
                                   };    
                                        html +=
                                        '<a class="result-link" title=" " style="text-decoration: none" href="' + item.link + '" style="font-size: 11px" >' +
                                          '<div class="result-image">' +
                                             ' <figure>' +
                                                  '<img src="' + item.enclosure + '" style="display: block;"></img>' +
                                              '</figure>' +
                                          '</div>' +
                                          '<div class="alltext" style="padding-right: 5px;">' +
                                              '<h3 class="result-title">' + item.title +'</h3>' +
                                              '<div class="result-description">' + item.description +'</div>' +
                                           '</div></a>'

                    });

           jQuery('#result').html(html);
       });
   });

    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    }

I also have my footer navigation bar in footer.html file which will be loaded in index.html file as follows:

  <script>
        $(document).on('pageinit', "#index", function (event, ui){
                                 $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=footer]").load("pages/footer.html", function(){
                                         $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=navbar]").navbar();
                                   });
                  });

    </script>

     <body>
    <div data-role="page" class="app" id="index">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="main-header" id="header">
            <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="grid" data-theme="b" data-iconpos="left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="home" data-theme="b"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" id="deviceready">
            <div id="result" data-role="listview">
            </div>                
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="main-footer" id="footer">
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

My problem is that I can't load my page footer navbar in my RSS pages, I saw some relevant examples about it and applied different approaches, but still have the same problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the persistent navbar demo: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-fixed-persistent/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the RSS page just another jQuery Mobile page in your site, or is it the original page in another site?

Comment: No it's not a seperate page, I have only one page in my app with header, content and footer and glue RSS links to the content with jQuery('#result').html(html); .  RSS liks are external links that I intend to open them inside my app (not in a brower) with the same header and footer, but they disappeared when I click on them.

Comment: Can you show the code for opening the external links?

Comment: Please take a look to my html variable, I have <a> tag which generate the items dynamically.

Comment: I also made some changes in my code, I removed the RSS links (item.link) from href attribute and leave it as a input in onclick function like this:                                                                                                    <a class="result-link" href="#" onclick="openUrl('+ item.link +')" title=" " style="text-decoration: none !important" style="font-size: 11px" >'    and then tryied to open the links with onclick() event, but still sme result.

Comment: We need to see your openUrl code.

Comment: it's not fired properly yet, but this is what I have at this moment with a hardcoded url:                                                                                $('.result-link').click(function(e){
                                               var $this = $(this);
                                               $this.attr('onclick', 'openUrl("https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser")');

                        });

Comment: But what does openUrl() do? if you want same header and footer, you must load another jQM data-role="page" with the link contents. How are you doing that?